# MongoDB : querying documents with two equal fields, $match and $eq

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, aggregation-framework, database

What is the best way to return all documents in a collection if I want document.a == document.b?

I've tried

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { $match: { $eq: [ '$a', '$b' ] } }])
```

But it returns with no errors or results, because I assume it is literally matching strings "$a" and "$b".  Is there a different way to specify that these are fields?

```
db.collection.aggregate([    { $project: { 
    eq: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ '$a', '$b' ] }, 1, 0 ] } 
} },
{ $match: { eq: 1 } }])
```

The above works, but requires the additional step of querying again with whatever documents it found or projecting all possible fields.

Is there a better way for achieving this query?

Comment: Thank to your question and the way you use to replace matching, I solve one of my problems ! In fact, I used `$addFields` instead of `$project`, in order to keep database structure like match do.

Comment: You can use aggregation expression in regular query in 3.6. Something like `db.collection.find( {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$a", "$b"]}})` and in aggregation thru `db.collection.aggregate( {"$match":{"$expr": {"$eq": ["$a", "$b"]}}})`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, you are trying to perform a self join. An operation not supported by MongoDB.

Concerning the `$eq` operator, as you guessed:

- By design, the [`$eq` comparison query operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) match a field against a *value*.
- But the [`$eq` comparison aggregation operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) compare the value of two *expressions*.

I don't know any other way to perform what you need than using an extra `$project` step as you suggested.

Please note this is not *significantly* more expensive as, anyway, your query cannot use any index and MongoDB will do a full scan.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way to index the relationship between two fields for something as simple as equal/not equal?

Answer (score 16):

If I understood your question right you want those documents that have same values in field1 and field2.

For this try

```
db.coll.find({$where: function() { return this.field1 == this.field2 } } );
```

or more compact

```
db.coll.find({ $where : "this.field1 == this.field2" } );
```

Comment: I would point out that `$where` clauses [cannot use indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations), and may result in **poor performance**. To explore your query's performance, [read about cursor.explain()](https://medium.com/dbkoda/8a3d0c6c7e68)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AWS DocumentDb and `$expr` isn't supported (as of 16 May 2023).  I used NatNgs's suggestion to use `$addFields` to compare two fields in the same document:

```
db.collection.aggregate($addFields: {
  "matchedValue" : {
    $cond: {
      if: {
        "$eq" : [ "$a", "$b" ]
      },
      then: "$a",
      else: false
    }
  }
});
```

This adds `matchedValue` field to the document but now we have a value we can filter on.

I used one more $match stage to filter out the `false` values.