# Linq to mongodb: unexpected behaviour in subquery condition

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query

There is a class persons, which knows several authors and has a favored author:

```
  public class Author
  {
    public string name;
    public string firstname;
  }

  public class Person
  {
    public string favoredAuthor;
    public Author[] knownAuthors;
  }
```

The json represantation looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b2955cf79cd67d3d09ddbe8"),
    "knownAuthors" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Müllmann",
            "firstname" : "Dieter"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Marx",
            "firstname" : "Karl"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Hildebrandt",
            "firstname" : "Saftarsch"
        }
    ],
    "favoredAuthor" : "Marx"
}
```

I want to query the -Author- which is favored by the person using following linq expression:

```
// gives no result:
var favoredAuthor = persons.AsQueryable()
    .Select(x => x.knownAuthors.Where(a => a.name == x.favoredAuthor))
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

The same works if I work on a List of Persons:

```
// working (result is Author 'Karl Marx'):
var persons = new List<Person>() { new Person() }.AsQueryable();
var person = persons.Select(x => x.knownAuthors.Where(a => a.name == x.favoredAuthor).FirstOrDefault()) 
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Is this a bug in official MongoDB driver? Or am I doing wrong?
I tested with 
  Visual Studio 2017
  MongoDb driver 2.7.0  and also 2.6.1

Any ideas, guys and girls?

Comment: The problem is not the subquery, but the comparison of two fields of the same document ("self join"). In my case, the solution is to add a property isFavoredAuthor to the Author class.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB can't handle comparing two fields like that. It's a limitation of the database system; see [MongoDB : querying documents with two equal fields, $match and $eq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762987/mongodb-querying-documents-with-two-equal-fields-match-and-eq?rq=1) for example and potential workarounds (be sure to understand the performance cost).

The last time we had this scenario, we documented the hell out of it and made sure to apply the `foo == bar` condition with LINQ-to-Objects after getting the dataset from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! 
Can you recommend a better design for this purpose?
 a) I want to store all known authors. 
 b) I want to reference the favored author. 
 c) I want to query the favored author without loading the whole document or all authors.
 d) I do not want to store duplicates of authors

Comment: Sounds pretty relational to me... have you considered using MySQL/MSSQL/etc.? Store authors in one table, persons in another, and relationship table "knownAuthors" with personid / authorid, favoriteAuthorId becomes a field on table persons, enforce referential integrity to validate that the favorite author is in knownAuthors.

If you must use Mongo, I don't think you're going to have an easy time meeting those criteria.