# Spring MongoDB : querying documents with two equal fields

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I want to query that returns document that two fields of it are equal

I found mongodb raw query from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762987/mongodb-querying-documents-with-two-equal-fields-match-and-eq) :

```
db.coll.find({ $where : "this.field1 == this.field2" } );
```

How can I perform it with spring criteria:

```
criteria = criteria.andOperator(
            Criteria.where("successfulSent").is("true"),
            Criteria.where("this.fieldOne == this.fieldTwo"));
```

but its not working beacuse generated query become :

```
  { ... "$and" : [ { "successfulSent" : "true"} , { "this.fieldOne == this.fieldOne " : { }}]}
```

Comment: What is your mongo version ?

Comment: @Veeram mongo 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try on this way:

```
Criteria.where("$where").is("this.field1 == this.field2")
```

Query toString() will be:

```
Query: { "$where" : "this.cts == this.uts"}, Fields: null, Sort: null
```