# Find by another field in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, variables, mongoose

how can i in mongoDB check field by another field like that in sql:

```
SELECT `name`,`surname` FROM `users` where `name`=`surname`
```

for now i try :

```
Credentials.findOne({ usersLen: { $lte: '$usersMaxLen' } });
                                            ^^^ - here i want access field usersMaxLen from collection
```

but have error:

```
CastError: Cast to number failed for value "$usersMaxLen" (type string) at path "usersLen" for model "Credentials"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762987/mongodb-querying-documents-with-two-equal-fields-match-and-eq/41470741

Comment: From the duplicates linked, your query should be `Credentials.findOne({ "$expr": { "$lte": ["$usersLen", "$usersMaxLen"] } });`